# Why do men's bicycles have a top tube while women's bicycles don't?

Tags: frames, bearings

Bicycles intended for men have a top tube that always hits me on ***that embrassing part*** when I brake.

[image]

Conversely, women's bikes often don't have a top tube. Why is this?

Comment: I'm totally leaving the tag for bearings.

Comment: The question that strikes me is... exactly how are you nutting yourself on the top tube when braking?    Nearest I've come was my front wheel stopping in a pothole while braking, and I was insufficiently braced, slid forward and struck the stem.  To hit the top tube you'd have to be moving forwards off the saddle and then downward.   Can you please expand?  I suspect your braking technique could be better.

Comment: I suspect he's braking to a stop and putting one or more feet down.

Comment: Or the bike is too big for them. you should have 2-3 inches of clearance from the top tube on a road bike, more for a mountain bike (which normally have more angled top tubes these days).

Comment: Unless you're in Scotland, men don't wear skirts.  And if your bike is properly sized you should have few problems with it striking you in an unpleasant spot.

Comment: @Criggie I've had a similarly painful experience when cheap wet brakes and chrome rims couldn't stop me but a kerb could. And what I hit was the steerer tube/stem.

Comment: Men also ride bikes that have "step through" geometry. Calling such a geometry a women's bike is kinda silly but understanable. This geometry is popular for city/utility bikes because it makes mounting/dismounting slightly easier because you don't have swing your leg over the seat from behind. Obviously this becomes more important for riders who are wearing a pencil skirt but it can be appreciated by folks wearing pants too.

Comment: This question always bugged me and I had no idea until I read about differences in male and male anatomy O:)

Comment: Duplicate of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/13826/740 ?

Comment: @ABcDexter Excuse me but what exactly prevents a woman from raising a leg? I don't think they got a problem with that, do they? Especially considering the multitudes of women in dancing.

Comment: @ChrisH When I left the saddle unintentionally I usually left the whole bike behind...

Comment: @katrmr Maybe women can get excited by landing on the saddle from behind. Landing from front side is much safer. Well, the question is why men do not prefer the same way - they can squeeze their pirvate parts, which is not exciting at all...

Comment: @Crowley me too generally speaking, but on this occasion I reached the end of the road and hit a 10-15cm kerb.  If it hadn't been there I'd have hit a wall or a pedestrian, turning either way I'd have hit a taxi.

Comment: Mountain bikes almost universally have dipped/kinked top tubes nowadays - the space thus opened up between your spuds and the frame is often referred to as "nad room".

Comment: "Unless you're in Scotland, men don't wear skirts" - Skirt-like garments are worn by men in far more cultures than Scotland. Also, while a skirt is perhaps as "gendered" as trousers were around 1900 in western society, you can certainly wear a skirt while identifying as male - perhaps just because you like it.

But regardless of garment, a lower top tube helps (dis)mounting. There is a reason that postal bikes, where riders frequently hop on and off, generally are of low-step construction.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Frames designed for women do have that part - its called a top tube.

Historically women wore skirts, so a lower frame in the middle made it easier to mount and dismount, and was less likely to accidentally show an ankle.

This picture shows a modern "woman's frame" with the top tube paralleling the downtube, and attaching to the seat tube lower down.

[image]

Positives:

- Skirts
- Ease of mounting

Negatives:

- Bike is flexier because of fewer triangles
- Bike is built heavier to reduce flex

Another frame designed for with these positives is the Mixte frame, where the top tube is replaced by two separate tubes similar to chainstays and seatstays.  These pass around the seattube and terminate at the headtube and the rear dropout, increasing the stiffness of the bike.    They're still heavier than a normal Diamond Frame bike.

[image]

Here's a photo of a Peugot showing the twin tubes.

[image]

Finally - there's absolutely nothing wrong with a woman riding a DF bike frame.  The main differences now are about proportions, not whether the rider wears a skirt.  There are situations where a man fits a "woman's frame" better than a "man's frame"

Comment: Actually, the Mixte is only marginally heavier than the equivalent diamond frame.  The main problem with the design is that it's *too stiff*.

Comment: Of course there's also an in between frame (common on women's MTBs) with a single "top" tube on a similar angle to the twin tubes of the mixte (sloping but not as much as a step-through)

Comment: Not just historically. Plenty of women still wear skirts.

Comment: And there are also step-through frame with no top-tube at all, or just a short (<~20cm) brace between the down tube and the seat post.  And many similar systems.

Comment: @ChrisH True - all variations on the same concept of "lowering the top tube"

Comment: @vsz True, but I think the implication was that historically it would've been unacceptable for a woman to wear pants in order to ride a bicycle. That's less true now.

Comment: @ChrisH Why it is too stiff? Or how can it be stiffer than men's diamond-shaped frame?

Comment: Regarding stiffness: I have two bike (frames) with the Mixte design + a normal high top tube, which makes each and every tube fully redundant. As such, they should be even stiffer than the Mixte, and I never noticed them flexing in any way. But they are both wonderful bikes to ride. The reason why I prefer this redundant frame design is that it would fail in a totally safe manner: Even if one tube breaks, two other tubes remain which still form a safe, stable triangle. I've come to distrust frames without this redundancy because I have already had two downtubes fail me. @Crowley

Answer (score 38):

Back in the day, women primarily wore dresses, and getting the dress over the top tube was difficult and awkward. So the women's bike was developed with a slanted or sloped top tube so women could step though with their dresses and ride without their dresses coming up.

Although the top tube shouldn't be hitting you in that "embarrassing part" when you're braking, regardless of it being a men's bike or women's.

[image]

Comment: This woman must be doing an impressive track stand, considering how long photograph exposures were!

Comment: @Criggie Good point! And all this while looking totally relaxed... Or it was some early occurrence of Photoshop ;-)

Comment: The first "snapshot" exposures were around 1878, but she might be bolted to the wall I suppose.

Comment: @BenediktBauer: yeah, but it wasn't that easy back then... that's clearly a greenscreen backdrop, but they couldn't be bothered to edit it out completely.

Comment: Props were very common back then, right up to unpleasant-looking "hold your head still" clamps. In this case a stick from her bum to the floor behind her right shoe would not be visible.

Comment: No photoshop required, this is exactly the same tricks as "floating on the air" magic.  a thick plank extended from the screen to the person, and support fork that make the bicycle steady. Paint those stuff with similar background colour. Then position the camera.

Comment: Look from the axle of the back wheel pointing down to the left almost 45º. That looks like *some* kind of artifact!

Comment: There are wires and anchors holding the bike up; you can see the left-side anchor in the background immediately behind the front wheel. You can see where the right-side wire was painted out (because they were hardcore then and did the “photo shop” directly on the originals!) by looking for the line of fuzziness between the rear hub and the fold in the dropcloth nearest the left edge of the photo.

Answer (score 2):

Women's bicycles have the front tube designed to curve down for their skirts, else while moving fast against the air may cause embarrassment whilst in public.

Comment: What does that even mean o.O

Comment: A girl with short skirts on a bicycle ( men's design with straight front tube) against heavy wind may be embarrassed.

Comment: Similarly, men should avoid excessively loose fitting shorts (or indeed skirts or kilts) when on a recumbent. Especially near bees.

Comment: @armb oh how I wish I could +100 that response! Gold! LOL