# How do manufacturers designate women specific designs on their bicycles?

Tags: frames, serial-number

Is there a tell-tale sticker or serial number code that can be parsed to tell if a frame is intended for men or women? Basically, can I take a serial number sticker and lookup somehow what physical sex it was designed for?

As an example if you consider the following bike [search](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchResult/Default.aspx?searchTerm=Trek%20%20Cronus) for a `Trek Chronus` and search the hits for *women* you'll find 2 hits. At first glance they don't stand out all that much from all the other frames besides them, so I'm wondering if I were faced with buying a used one, how could I tell which bucket it landed in?

Comment: There are no global databases of serial numbers so, no, that option isn't going to work.

Comment: Mostly size, in the mind of some makers women seem to be microscopic. Bust mostly stereotyped colour. But as with any bike, the fit makes it, the rest is quite secondary.

Comment: You might look at [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/13826/what-are-the-differences-between-mens-and-womens-bike-frames).  It is not exactly what you are asking, but along the line.

Comment: Colour coding - Pink for women bike.

Comment: @Carel They are correct. My wife is microscopic in the vertical dimension. However her bust is not stereotypical colour.

Comment: @HenryCrun: Bl...dy autocorrect :-/

Comment: From what I've seen online, some people (including bike sellers) are trying to get rid of the man/woman naming for the models and instead just use the name of the frame shape (which I do not know in English). Both shapes have pros and cons (convenience, performance, durability) which could be of interest to anyone regardless of their gender. (I would have torn fewers pants with a so-called woman bike).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, it's impossible to tell anything from bicycle serial numbers. Manufacturers do not provide a way to look up serial numbers and get a model name or a description of the original configuration.

Some women's specific models are sometimes marks as such. When women's specific models started to appear they often had paint schemes based on pinks and purples, because these were thought to be 'women's colors'.